# My promise returns the same value every time it's called despite having different data?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

So first the getCart function is called in `b-navbar.component.ts`:

```ts
export class BNavbarComponent implements OnInit{
  appUser: any;
  cart$ : Observable<ShoppingCart | null>;


  constructor(private auth : AuthService, private shoppingCartService : ShoppingCartService) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.appUser$.then(dataObservable => {
      dataObservable?.subscribe(data => {
        this.appUser = data
      });
    });

    this.getCart()
  }

  async getCart() {
    this.cart$ = await this.shoppingCartService.getCart()
    
    this.cart$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Nav Observable data: ", data);
    })
  }
```

Which looks in `shopping-cart.service.ts` and gets a promise of an observable:

```ts
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create(){
    return this.db.list("/shopping-carts").push({
      // dateCreated : new Date().getTime()
      date: "date"
    });
  }
  
  async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>>{
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let cart = this.db.object("/shopping-carts/" + cartId);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      cart.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
        let newX = x as ShoppingCart
        let items = newX.items
        resolve(of(new ShoppingCart(items)))
      })
    })
  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId() : Promise<string> {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem("cartId");
    
    if (cartId) return cartId;
    
    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem("cartId", result.key as string);
    return result.key as string;
  }
}
```

Now the issue arises when interpolate the values in my html, since the observable returned in the getCart promise resolves a "static" observable, meaning it terminates the observable when resolved, thus the data is never updated. Please help :))

```html
<a class="navbar-item" routerLink="/shopping-cart">
    Shopping Cart
    <span *ngIf = "cart$ | async as cart" class="tag is-warning is-rounded" >
        {{ cart.totalItemsCount }}
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Does `this.db.list("/shopping-carts").push({date: "date"})` in the `shopping-cart-service` return an array, a `Promise<Array`, or an `Observable<Array>`?

Comment: It returns : ```lang-ts AngularFireList<unknown>.push(data: unknown): firebase.database.ThenableReference ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your promise gets resolved, it **doesn't "emit" anything after that**. This is *one key difference between promises and obsevables*. Observables can emit more values even after they emit the first.

So, you should make your getCart return just the observable stream:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs';

// rest of your code

async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>>{
  let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
  let cart = this.db.object("/shopping-carts/" + cartId);
  return cart.valueChanges()
    .pipe(map(x => {
      let newX = x as ShoppingCart
      let items = newX.items
      return new ShoppingCart(items)
    }))
}
```

This way, your promise resolves to the observable stream instead of a single value.